# MongoDB - ReWriting Java 8 method in Java 7?

Tags: java, mongodb, java-8, mongodb-query, java-7

I have the following `Java` method that searches `MongoDB` for a specific entry:

```
  public List<Document> search(String collection, String entry){
        List<Document> documentList = new ArrayList<>();

        createIndexforCollection(collection);
        getCollection(collection).find(Filters.text(entry)).forEach((Block<? super Document>) documentList::add);

        return documentList;
    }
```

The above makes use of `Java 8` features e.g. `documentList::add` , however in the Project I am working on I am only able to use `Java 7`.

How can I re-write the above the have the same logic `using Java 7`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code.

```
List<Document> documentList = new ArrayList<>();
MongoCursor<Document> cursor = getCollection(collection).find(Filters.text(entry)).iterator();
while(cursor.hasNext()) {
  Document document = cursor.next();
  documentList.add(document;  
}
```

Comment: Sorry typo. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 try(final DBCursor dbCursor = mongoTemplate.getCollection("YourCollectionName").find(Filters.text(entry))) {      
            while (dbCursor.hasNext()) {
              Document document = dbCursor.next(); // You need to cast to the type you need
              documentList.add(document);
            }
   }
```